# html body is displaying left aligned but in css it is set to centered

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of questions. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/POZR2/

Firstly if you scroll to the right you will see a white space, if you change the size of the screen/result box the size of the white space gets larger/smaller. The css for this is under the 'full' div and is:

```
#full{ background-color:#262626}
```

Secondly even though div id noint_box1 is centered in css it appears to be aligned left. This div is basically the 'body' of the html from the first heading to the last picture.

Thnkas

Answer (score 0):

your table is inheriting your centering, but not using it. add margins to it if you want it centered

```
table { margin: auto; }
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Give `#full` a `min-width` of `1061px` - this for the first of the two issues.

For the other one... well, I'm not quite sure it's this that you want, but try applying  the following rules to `#noint_box1`:

```
width: 958px;
margin: 18px auto;
```

Comment: Great that worked thanks, Also on the iphone ebay app i have to scroll right to see the full page, is there anyway I can fit it automatically to fit the page?